# CreateProcess - First thread routine - where is the memory allocated for the thread?

Tags: windows, memory, winapi, thread, process

When calling `CreateProcess` internally it will call (obviously `ZwCreateProcessEx` and then) `ZwCreateThread` with a `CreateSuspended` set to `True`, then i assume final initialization is taking place. Afterwards it is calling `ZwResumeThread` and then everything is working as it should.

My question is focused on the `ZwCreateThread` function:
http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FThread%2FNtCreateThread.html

Where exactly in this whole `CreateProcess` Routine, it is allocating the memory in the remote process for the `ThreadStartRoutine` Parameter, which in the ZwCreateThread, is the parameter `ThreadContext->EAX`, i have seen a couple of NtAllocateVirtualMemory with `Protect` of value `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE - 0x40` but none of them is allocating the memory for the `NewThreadRoutine`.. so where exactly the Thread entrypoint is being allocated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer:  The implementation of these APIs is likely to change between versions of Windows.  I will be referencing 32-bit Windows XP SP3 in my answer.  Your results may vary.

### How thread creation works

There are three structures that must be initialized before calling [`NtCreateThread`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FThread%2FNtCreateThread.html):

1. [`INITIAL_TEB`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/struct___i_n_i_t_i_a_l___t_e_b.html): Contains pointers to the stack region
2. [`CONTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679284(v=vs.85).aspx): Contains the register state
3. [`OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557749(v=vs.85).aspx): Contains security attributes for the thread

In my implementation, there are dedicated functions that handle each of these tasks: `BaseCreateStack`, `BaseInitializeContext`, and `BaseFormatObjectAttributes`, respectively.

The `BaseInitializeContext` function is the one you're interested in, however, since the new thread will begin at `CONTEXT.Eip`.

Interestingly, `BaseInitializeContext` instead puts the thread's start address (i.e. the entry point of the new process) in `CONTEXT.Eax`.  And `CONTEXT.Eip` is set to the address of `BaseProcessStartThunk`.  (Since `kernel32` is mapped at the same address in every process, we know this will also be the address of `BaseProcessStartThunk` in the other process)

So when we call `NtCreateThread`, we start a new thread in the other process at `BaseProcessStartThunk` with `eax` equal to the entry point.

`BaseProcessStartThunk` saves the start address from register `eax`. It sets the start address internally by calling [`NtSetInformationThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567101(v=vs.85).aspx) with a `ThreadInformationClass` of `ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress` (see `ntddk.h`).  It then calls the start address.  Finally, when the thread returns, it calls `ExitThread`.

### How the executable image is mapped into the new process

If you want to know the process was created in the first place, we have to go back a few steps.

First, a handle to the new process executable is opened via [`NtOpenFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567011(v=vs.85).aspx).

The file handle is used to create a [section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563684(v=vs.85).aspx) object via [`NtCreateSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566428(v=vs.85).aspx).

A call to [`NtQuerySection`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FSection%2FNtQuerySection.html) with `InformationClass` set to `SectionImageInformation` is made.  This parses the the section object and fills out a [`SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FStructures%2FSECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION.html) structure, which most notably includes fields the `EntryPoint` field.  This is how the entry point of the new process is determined.

Eventually, [`NtCreateProcessEx`](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d2/d9f/ntoskrnl_2ps_2process_8c_source.html) is called, given the section handle from `NtCreateSection` as a parameter.  This is what actually creates the new process and maps the executable image into the new process' address space, among many other things.  `NtCreateProcessEx` also provides the process handle that we pass to `NtCreateThread` to create the new thread.

Comment: this is hilarious, microsoft were the first to implement injection methods ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ok so ZwCreateThread has it in the context structure (PCONTEXT + 0xB0)

The api calls to receive the address are like this:
`CreateSection(..SectionInformation..)` - Probably to create to initial address

`NtQuerySection(Handle, x, SectionInformation, x, x)`

This SectionInformation is containing the address of the EntryPoint of the remote process, later initializing the `ThreadContext` with the function `_BaseInitializeContext@20` and then using `ZwCreateThread`...

This was all checked under windows xp, hopefully it will be of use for someone